# How do I choose what name a instance should have without creating it directly?

Tags: c#, list, object

I was trying to create a basic RPG game when this problem occurred to me, how do I decide what should I put in the argument of the function `EquipWeapon()` when I create an instance of a `Weapon` without assigning it a "name"/"identifier":

```
    public static void CreateWeapon( string name, int attack, int defense)
    {
        Weapon created_weapon = new Weapon(name, attack, defense);
        weapon_list.Add(created_weapon);
    }
```

That is inside the class "Weapon", while this is inside the class "Player", in another file.

```
    public static void EquipWeapon(Weapon weapon)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stats:");
        Weapon.CompareWeaponStats(weapon, Player.equipped_weapon);
        Console.WriteLine("Are you sure you want to equip this weapon?") ;
        if (QuestionPrompt() == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Equipped weapon!");
            ChangeWeapon(weapon);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You will continue with the same weapon, the new one was discarded.");
        }
    }
```

Also, is there a easier way to add the newly created instance to the list `weapon_list`, and being able to access it by the weapons "code" or "name"?

I'm a beginner in C# so please explain to me in a way that I can understand. I tried to search for this solution everywhere but didn't found it. If there's any missing code that's necessary for the resolution of the problem I'll post it here if needed.

Comment: using System.Linq namespace, will enable you to query the list by the property 'Name'. For eg: weapon_list.Where(w=>w.name.Equals('Sword').FirstOrDefault();

Comment: I think I did that without using that lol, check my answer and tell me if it's good or not pls

Comment: I would have preferred the Linq style, less lines and more readable. It's up to you :)

Comment: Maybe you can store it in a `Dictionary<string, Weapon>`?

Comment: Tony Mathew, I don't know how to use that library, but I'll take a look into it, and vasily.ib, I don't know what a dictionary is in C#, but it doesn't really matter now xD

Answer (score 0):

Guys I managed to surpass the problem by Equipping the weapon with its name, instead of its "identifier"(idk how it is called).

```
        public static void EquipWeapon(string weapon_name)
        {
            Weapon weapon_to_equip = new Weapon("Test Weapon", 0, 0);

            bool WeaponExists()
            {
                foreach (Weapon weapon in Weapon.weapon_list)
                {
                    if (weapon.name == weapon_name)
                    {
                        weapon_to_equip = weapon;
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            if (WeaponExists())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Stats:");
                Weapon.CompareWeaponStats(weapon_to_equip, Player.equipped_weapon);
                Console.WriteLine("Are you sure you want to equip this weapon?");
                if (QuestionPrompt() == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You equipped the weapon!");
                    ChangeWeapon(weapon_to_equip);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You will continue with the same weapon, the new one was discarded.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The weapon you want to equip doesn't exist!");
            }
        }
```